# IE Date.parse method returns NaN for Date with Time string

Tags: javascript

We are trying parse the date with timestamp string, it blows up in IE but works fine FireFox.

Here are the code

alert(new Date(Date.parse("2010-01-31T12:00:00.233467-05:00")));

Any idea to make it work in IE browser?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

If you can put your input in this form:

```
YYYY/MM/DDThh:mm:ss
```

It will work.

Eg:

```
alert(new Date(Date.parse('2010-01-31T12:00:00.233467-05:00'.replace(/\-/ig, '/').split('.')[0])));
```

If you want the time zone, then you will have to find another way

Comment: It appears that Firefox and Opera behave the same way.  IE and Safari behave the same way too.

Comment: I tested this with IE8 and found I had to also remove the 'T' to get the correct time. i.e.  `date.replace(/\-/ig, '/').replace(/T/, ' ').split('.')[0]`