# convert date from DD-MMM-YY to YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: javascript, date

How to convert date from `DD-MMM-YY` to `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can use the standard `Date.parse` function to convert from a string to a Date:

```
> new Date(Date.parse("01-Jan-09"));
Thu Jan 01 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Now, you need to serialize the date, which you can do like this:

```
function serialize(date) {
  return '' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() +1) + '-' + date.getDate();
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but `new Date(Date.parse("01-Jan-09"));` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does `Date.parse()` work in IE < 9?

Comment: I don't know...I am on Chrome and mac.  IE < 9 doesn't exist in my world. :)

Comment: Well there is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513441/date-parse-doesnt-work-in-ie-8)...

Comment: All right...that's not a good response. But the point remains that there is a parse step and then a serialize step.

Comment: It's not working for me. i am working on IE8.

Comment: This question has a workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513441/date-parse-doesnt-work-in-ie-8

Comment: And my answer is actually not complete since you need to have your month and day padded with an extra 0.

Comment: It's not `getDay` but `getDate`. `getDay` gives you day of week I believe..