# Updating multiple <span>'s individually when specific time inside <span>'s match the current time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make an EPG which is supposed to update automatically when the current time reaches the "endtime".

My code basically looks something like this... sorry 'bout the ugly markup.

```
<span class="channel">
    <span class="channum">01</span>
    TV1
</span>
<span id="tv1" class="showing">
    <span class="starttime">22:30</span> 
    Program Title
    <span class="progresscontainer">
        <span class="progressbar" style="width:50%"></span>
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="endtime">23:00</span> Program Title
</span>

<span class="channel">
    <span class="channum">02</span>
    TV2
</span>
<span id="tv2" class="showing">
    <span class="starttime">22:15</span> 
    Program Title
    <span class="progresscontainer">
        <span class="progressbar" style="width:0%"></span>
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="endtime">23:30</span> 
    Program Title
</span>

<span class="channel">
    <span class="channum">03</span>
    TV3
</span>
<span id="tv3" class="showing">
    <span class="starttime">21:45</span> 
    Program Title
    <span class="progresscontainer">
        <span class="progressbar" style="width:75%"></span>
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="endtime">22:30</span> 
    Program Title
</span>
```

How do you compare the time inside `<span class="endtime">` with the current time and load the content from `tv1.php` `tv2.php` and `tv3.php` into the respective `<span>`'s with the corresponding `id`'s?

I'm not that strong in jquery so this is all I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var hh = d.getHours();
    var mm = d.getMinutes();
    if (hh < 10) {hh = '0' + hh;}
    if (mm < 10) {mm = '0' + mm;}
    var time = hh + ':' + mm;

    $('.showing').each(function(){
        var epg = $(this).attr('id') + '.php';
        $(this).load(epg);
    });
});
```

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Tip: You have missing open `span` tags somewhere.

Comment: I count seven open and close span tags.

Comment: Yes, my bad. It's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `script` would be a good start. You'll need to adjust it to consider shows starting/finishing in different dates:

```
$(function() {
    var now = new Date();

    // For easy comparison.
    now.setSeconds(0);
    now.setMilliseconds(0);

    // For debugging.
    $('.now').text(now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes());

    $('.showing').each(function(){
        // Finding out the start time.
        var start = new Date(
            now.getFullYear(), 
            now.getMonth(), 
            now.getDate(), 
            parseInt($(this).find('.starttime').text().split(':')[0], 10), 
            parseInt($(this).find('.starttime').text().split(':')[1], 10), 
            0, 
            0);

        // Finding out the end time.
        var end = new Date(
            now.getFullYear(),
            now.getMonth(), 
            now.getDate(),
            parseInt($(this).find('.endtime').text().split(':')[0], 10), 
            parseInt($(this).find('.endtime').text().split(':')[1], 10), 
            0, 
            0);

        if (now <= end && now >= start) {        
            var epg = $(this).attr('id') + '.php';

            // Removed for debugging.
            //$(this).load(epg);

            // For debugging.
            $(this).html('<b>' + epg + '</b>');
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/8jsraxyp/1/)

Comment: Thanks @MelanciaUK - with the required adjustments to the script it works perfectly :)
Now all that needs be to added to script is a calculation of the `progressbar` width in percent based on the `starttime`, `endtime` and `now`.
Can you help me with this as well or should I open a new question on that specific matter?

Comment: You should open a new question to keep the SO rules/standards. :)

Comment: Something you should refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980827/difference-between-two-times-as-percentage-in-javascript