# Javascript running Date Time return value is working in chrome but not in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function to run time in different manner.
Its working well in Chrome browser but its not showing proper value in Internet Explorer.

**In Chrome:**

> 13-Dec-2011 13:14:19

**In IE8:**

> 0NaN-undefined-NaN 0NaN:0NaN:0NaN

You can view this from this [page link](http://chemfluence.org.in/monetarist/sample.php) from both the browsers. Also look at the source code of page
http://chemfluence.org.in/monetarist/sample.php

**My Code:**

```
 <div id="txt" title="Industries will generate products on every 3 Virtual days. 
 12 Virtual Days = 1 Real day. dd-Mon-yyyy HH:MM:SS ."></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

var virtualOrigin = Date.parse("2012-02-27T00:00:00"),
    game_start_realdate=Date.parse("2013-01-27T12:00:00"),
    realOrigin = Date.now(),
    factor = 12;

function getVirtual(time) {
    return new Date( virtualOrigin + ((time - realOrigin) * factor)  +(realOrigin-game_start_realdate)*factor);
}

function pad2(num) {
    return ("0"+num).substr(-2);
}
function format(time) {
var month=new Array();
month[0]="Jan";
month[1]="Feb";
month[2]="Mar";
month[3]="Apr";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="Jun";
month[6]="Jul";
month[7]="Aug";
month[8]="Sep";
month[9]="Oct";
month[10]="Nov";
month[11]="Dec";
     return pad2(time.getDate())
        + "-" + month[time.getMonth()]
        + "-" + time.getFullYear()
        + " " + pad2(time.getHours())
        + ":" + pad2(time.getMinutes())
        + ":" + pad2(time.getSeconds());
}

function startTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var display = getVirtual(now);
    output.innerText = format(display);
    setTimeout(startTime, 1000/factor - (now.getMilliseconds() % (1000/factor)));
}

var output = document.getElementById("txt");
startTime();

</script>
```

I need the above Javascript to be modified to work in Internet Explore and Chrome/Firefox;
**Please give me modified code;**

Comment: I don't think Internet Explorer can parse that date format.

Comment: @Pointy : then what can be done ?

Comment: you can find a possible solution for IE here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3046647/828197

Comment: Well it may be that a library like [Date.JS](http://datejs.com) would be something to try.

Comment: Or `moment.js`. That is the best one I've ever used. http://momentjs.com

Comment: @brenjt : Can i have some sample please ?

Comment: @Ragnarokkr : Now its reversed; IE working but chrome not working;
check http://chemfluence.org.in/monetarist/sample.php

Comment: A simple example: `moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');`

Comment: @logan of course if you do as explained into the answer at the link, you have also to check if on IE or Chrome/FF/Opera/etc. otherwise what is right for IE is wrong for the other. Probably for what you need  is better [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @brenjt : Do i need to use moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); in place of Date.Parse ?

Comment: Not exactly. Refer to the documentation here on exactly how to use it. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: @brenjt : it requires,  <script src="moment.min.js"> ; will it be called automatically. And this one solution be compatible for Chrome & IE ?

Comment: Yes it requires the js library. It should work as long as that is included. It is cross browser compliant. You can run the tests here to be certain. http://momentjs.com/test/

Comment: I have started Bounty to get Answers not just hints... Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using moment.js. it is cross browser and can make doing dates in javascript much less of a pain. The documentation is very thorough. http://momentjs.com/docs/

You can format your date with as little as:

`var day = moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");`

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of it's full usage.

```
var mysql_date = '2013-01-25 10:00:00'; // Date from MySQL database

/**
 * @param     string     mysql_data     Date string
 * @param     string     format         Format in which mysql_data is set
 */
var date = moment(mysql_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // new moment.js object.

// To display the date in a different format use:
var date_format1 = date.format('MMM, Do'); // Format here would be Jan, 25th
var date_format2 = date.format('MMMM, Do, YYYY'); // January, 25th, 2013

console.log(date_format1, date_format2);
```

You can change the format when ever you want. You don't need to recreate it again.

Comment: I am a beginner to Javascript. So if you could please help with my current code , it will be much useful and appreciated.

Comment: Its not working... nothing is displayed..
If you have any sample PLEASE show me ...

Answer (score 2):

Take a custom parse function to be sure that you can parse that date format whatever the browser is:

```
function parse(datestring){
    var timearray = datestring.split(/[\-T\:]/g)
    return +new Date(+timearray[0],timearray[1]-1,+timearray[2],+timearray[3],+timearray[4],+timearray[5])
}
```

And fix the `pad2` function to work with IE8 by not using `substr` with a negative value:

```
function pad2(num) {
    return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: after adding your function I modified to .    var virtualOrigin = parse("2012-02-27T00:00:00"),
        game_start_realdate=parse("2013-01-27T12:00:00"),
Now its not working in both the browsers.. shows aN-undefined-NaN aN:aN:aN

Comment: Sorry, in a hurry I missed that you expect a number rather than a `Date` obejct from `parse`. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Hi, i have got answer from brenjt... Thats working fine.. But you have corrected me from using pad2() function.. So i give up vote for that. Thanks for your Time :)